# Keep Text within a Div

Tags: html, css

I have made several attempts at trying to keep the text within the boxes but even with adding a p.class. I can't get it to conform please have a look I have a jsfiddle with my attempt.
`<html> </html>`
http://jsfiddle.net/gerryboy/57uGQ/35/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

just add

```
white-space:normal;
```

to your `p` class.

here is the updated fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57uGQ/36/)

The [white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) property specifies how white-space inside an element is handled.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this to see the result :-)

```
p.excerpt {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-width:250px;
    text-align:center;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Good luck :)